# Segregation Data in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a complex Id in my Data Base table Like is 00-000-000.
All names store in one field

```
01-000-000=Warehouse
01-001-000-=Rack
01-001-001=Bin cart
```

into the same table. I want to segregate data in 3 different fields. Is it possible in SQL?

Comment: That's called normalization, not segregation. It's possible but you have to write the code to do it. Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: Yes of course it is. But you have to define better what you need and also, at least show some attempt. As a tip you can use an update function with substring functions. Try something then you add it here if you can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

there is another method with parsename function

```
select PARSENAME(replace(left(FieldName,10),'-','.'),3) col1,
PARSENAME(replace(left(FieldName,10),'-','.'),2) col2,
PARSENAME(replace(left(FieldName,10),'-','.'),1) col3 from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have quite enough information I am assuming that you wish to split the 3 number identifier at the start of each row into the 3 separate numbers...

If the Ids are always of fixed length (i.e. 2 letters then a dash then 3 letters then a dash then 3 more letters), you can use the substring function to break them out;

```
WITH TestData as (
    SELECT '01-000-000=Warehouse' AS Id
    UNION 
    SELECT '01-001-000-=Rack' AS Id
    UNION 
    SELECT '01-001-001=Bin cart' AS Id
)
SELECT 
    Id,
    substring(Id, 0, 2) AS FirstId,
    substring(Id, 4, 3) AS SecondId,
    substring(Id, 8, 3) AS ThirdId,
    substring(Id, 11, len(id) - 10) AS RestOfString
FROM TestData
```

If they are variable lengths you will have to use something like the CHARINDEX function to find the positions of the dashes, and then split on them.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be the same length then you can do some simple code using LEFT and RIGHT

Test Data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (FieldName varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #TestData (FieldName)
VALUES
('01-000-000=Warehouse')
,('01-001-000-=Rack')
,('01-001-001=Bin cart')
```

Query;

```
SELECT
FieldName
,LEFT(FieldName,2) Result1
,RIGHT(LEFT(FieldName,6),3) Result2
,RIGHT(LEFT(FieldName,10),3) Result3
FROM #TestData
```

Result;

```
FieldName               Result1 Result2 Result3
01-000-000=Warehouse    01      000     000
01-001-000-=Rack        01      001     000
01-001-001=Bin cart     01      001     001
```

Comment: i need Warehouse , rack , Bin Cart separate not id

Comment: my id first head store warehouse and second head store rack and third Bin cart

Comment: i need result in this shape col-1 warehoue col-2 rack col-3 bin cart

Comment: Update your question and show exactly what result you want. The number of columns and what data they should each hold

Answer (score 0):

Use this for dynamic value with 2 "-" sign.

```
    SELECT  SUBSTRING('001-0011-0010',1,CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010')-1) COLA,     
            SUBSTRING   ('001-0011-0010',
                                CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010')+1,
                                CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010',
                                CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010')+1)-(CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010')+1)
                                ) COLB,
                    SUBSTRING   ('001-0011-0010',(CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010',
                                CHARINDEX('-','001-0011-0010')+1))+1, LEN('001-0011-0010')
                                ) COLC
```

Thanks